# Async Socket Sending Problem after Control.Invoke method

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous, asyncsocket

I have got a Client/Server Application that using Asynchronous Socket.I have got a method for sending data to client from server side and client got a method for handle this data and control client's forms control.

Because of using Async socket I need to use `Control.Invoke` method for access Main Thread. But i got a problem--after I use `Control.Invoke` it starts data sending problem to Server Side. Its get into socketClient.Send(byteArray); but not sending data to server. If i dont use Invoke.Method i cant able to control client side forms controls :(

What I have to do?

Ok I found my problem but its not about Control.Invoke  its a socket data transmission issue.But i could not solve it.When i use repeadetly socketClient.Send() method only first socketclient.Send() is working other not. Here is my codes ;

// When client is connected this method is working.

```
void baglantiSaglandi(IAsyncResult sonuc){
  try
  {


    Aday gelenAday = new Aday();
    bagliAdayListesi.Add(gelenAday);
    gelenAday.adaySoket = serverSocket.EndAccept(sonuc);

    TamponTemizle();

    // Client'in gönderdiği veriyi kabul edip, boyutunu gelendataBoyutu isimli değişkene atadık.
    int gelendataBoyutu = gelenAday.adaySoket.Receive(tampon);
    // Client'in ip adresini ipadresi property imize ekledik.
    gelenAday.ipAdresi = Mesaj(StringeDonustur(tampon, gelendataBoyutu));
    lstKullanicilar.Items.Add(gelenAday.ipAdresi);

    grpYonetim.Enabled = true;
    lblUyari.Visible = false;
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(baglantiSaglandi), null);

    TamponTemizle();

    gelenAday.adaySoket.BeginReceive(tampon, 0, tampon.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(mesajGeldi), gelenAday);
  }
  catch (SocketException ex)
  {

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

//When Clients sent message to server this code block is working.

```
void mesajGeldi(IAsyncResult sonuc){
  Aday stateAday = sonuc.AsyncState as Aday;

  try
  {

    int gelenDataBoyutu = stateAday.adaySoket.EndReceive(sonuc);
    MesajKontrol(StringeDonustur(tampon, gelenDataBoyutu), stateAday.ipAdresi);

  }
  catch (SocketException ex)
  {
    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
    {
      foreach (Aday cikanAday in bagliAdayListesi)
      {
        if (cikanAday.ipAdresi == stateAday.ipAdresi)
        {
          cikanAday.adaySoket.Close();
          bagliAdayListesi.Remove(cikanAday);
          //  lstKullanicilar.Items.Remove(cikanAday.ipAdresi);
          if (lstKullanicilar.Items.Count <= 0)
          {
            grpYonetim.Enabled = false;
            lblUyari.Visible = true;
          }

          break;

        }
      }
    }


  }
}
```

//this method is handling Client's messages

```
void MesajKontrol(string mesaj, string aday)
{

  if (mesaj.Length < 1)
    return;

  switch (mesaj.Substring(0, 3))
  {


    case "/s/":

      string[] yanlisDogru = Mesaj(mesaj).Split(',');

      foreach (Aday cikanAday in bagliAdayListesi)
      {
        if (cikanAday.ipAdresi == aday)
        {
          lstKullanicilar.Items[bagliAdayListesi.IndexOf(cikanAday)].SubItems.Add(yanlisDogru[1]);
            lstKullanicilar.Items[bagliAdayListesi.IndexOf(cikanAday)].SubItems.Add(yanlisDogru[0]);

        }
      }

      break;

    case "/q/":
      foreach (Aday cikanAday in bagliAdayListesi)
      {
        if (cikanAday.ipAdresi == aday)
        {
          cikanAday.adaySoket.Close();
          bagliAdayListesi.Remove(cikanAday);
          //lstKullanicilar.Items.Remove(cikanAday.ipAdresi);
          if (lstKullanicilar.Items.Count <= 0)
          {
            grpYonetim.Enabled = false;
            lblUyari.Visible = true;
          }
          break;

        }
      }
      break;
    case "/b/":

      foreach (Aday cikanAday in bagliAdayListesi)
      {
        if (cikanAday.ipAdresi == aday)
        {

          lstKullanicilar.Items[bagliAdayListesi.IndexOf(cikanAday)].SubItems.Add(Mesaj(mesaj));
          lstKullanicilar.Items[bagliAdayListesi.IndexOf(cikanAday)].SubItems.Add("0");
          lstKullanicilar.Items[bagliAdayListesi.IndexOf(cikanAday)].SubItems.Add("0");

        }
      }

      break;



    default:
      break;

  }

}
```

//This code block is working from client side and the problems begin here there are 2 Send method working but only the first is executed at the server.

```
private void btnYazdir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      clientSocket.Send(ByteArrayeDonustur("/s/" + yanlis.ToString() + "," + dogru.ToString()));
      clientSocket.Send(ByteArrayeDonustur("/b/" + txtAdSoyad.Text));
    }
```

Comment: Please learn to use punctuation, spaces after periods, paragraphs. Please don't use "cuz", that is not a word. These things matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First

You're not using asynchronous sockets, if you were then you would either be calling [Socket.BeginSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginsend.aspx) or [Socket.SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx). Calling `Socket.Send` is not asynchronous, as a matter of fact it's **VERY synchronous!**

### Second

I don't see what the invoke method has to do with you not being able to send data either... you're currently describing a socket data transmission issue, but you're giving us a code sample that shows you calling invoke on the main thread which starts a `new Thread` and somehow that causes the socket to go [AWOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWOL#Absence_without_leave)!

### Third

Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) compliant code example which we can use to reproduce your problem (at the very least) or provide some more relevant code with regards to:

1. How you're sending data to the server.
2. What does the code invoked in the new thread do (i.e. does it do anything to the socket?)
3. What you do on the server side to receive the data.

### Update:

Here is my version... I start by making a method `BeginReceive`. It sets up the socket receiving and calls the `BeginReceive` method on the socket:

```
private void BeginReceive()
{
    if ( _clientState == EClientState.Receiving)
    {
        if (_asyncTask.BytesReceived != 0 && _asyncTask.TotalBytesReceived <= _maxPageSize)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            e.SetBuffer(_asyncTask.ReceiveBuffer, 0, _asyncTask.ReceiveBuffer.Length);
            e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(ReceiveCallback);
            e.UserToken = _asyncTask.Host;

            bool comletedAsync = false;
            try
            {
                comletedAsync = _socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error receiving data from: " + _asyncTask.Host);
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0} Error Code: {1}", se.Message, se.NativeErrorCode);

                ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
            }

            if (!comletedAsync)
            {
                // The call completed synchronously so invoke the callback ourselves
                ReceiveCallback(this, e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Num bytes received: " + _asyncTask.TotalBytesReceived);
            ChangeState(EClientState.ReceiveDone);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the receive callback (note that it calls `BeginReceive` again):

```
private void ReceiveCallback(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    lock (_sync) // re-entrant lock
    {
        // Fast fail: should not be receiving data if the client
        // is not in a receiving state.
        if (_clientState == EClientState.Receiving)
        {
            String host = (String)args.UserToken;

            if (_asyncTask.Host == host && args.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                try
                {
                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
                    _asyncTask.BytesReceived = args.BytesTransferred;
                    _asyncTask.TotalBytesReceived += _asyncTask.BytesReceived;
                    _asyncTask.DocSource += encoding.GetString(_asyncTask.ReceiveBuffer, 0, _asyncTask.BytesReceived);

                    BeginReceive(); // <---- THIS IS WHAT YOU'RE MISSING
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error receiving data from: " + host);
                    Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0} Error Code: {1}", e.Message, e.NativeErrorCode);

                    ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
                }
            }
            else if (_asyncTask.Host != host)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Warning: received a callback for {0}, but the client is currently working on {1}.",
                    host, _asyncTask.Host);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket Error: {0} when receiving from {1}",
                   args.SocketError,
                   _asyncTask.Host);
                ChangeState(EClientState.Failed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, you call this:

```
gelenAday.adaySoket.BeginReceive(tampon, 0, tampon.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(mesajGeldi), gelenAday);
```

In `mesajGeldi`, you're supposed to call the function that calls the above method. You should isolate that call in a method that only takes care of invoking begin/receive (as demonstrated by my example) and it doesn't do anything with establishing the socket connection.

Comment: yeah its like you said a socket transmission problem. I cant send repeadetly 2 Socket.Send() method. Only first is executing at server side. What can i do ?

Comment: @Ibrahim, so what happens when you all Send again? Do you get some type of error message, does something crash, or does the client simply send no data?

Comment: Client side is sending but Server side not catching message.Server is catching only first message.

Comment: Do you call `BeginReceive` on the server again (server side)? From callback on `BeginReceive` you should invoke the method that calls begin receive again. Here is my version asynchronous client/server: http://codesprout.blogspot.com/2011/04/asynchronous-http-client.html

Comment: I had only one BeginReceive Method that working after Client Connected but as you said i put second beginreceive in beginReceive's asyncallback method (after message come)..  no way its not working.

Comment: @Ibrahim, take a look at my example and look at it carefully. You need to get as close to my example as possible... obviously I can't run your code, so all I can do is point out that your server is only calling `BeginReceive` once. When it gets the first message, then it stops receiving data. You need to call `BeginReceive` until you're ready to stop.

Comment: Thank you very much.I solved it. I put second beginreceive to asyncallback method and clean buffer array.its working now

Comment: @Ibrahim, glad it worked... like I said: you have to call `BeginReceive` again :)